# Consolidate entries in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to consolidate the unique dates that some students do their homework.  Goal is to get the unique number of entries of date&name (i.e. multiple entries of one person on same date counts as one), and ideally the output can be the following.  I thought about using arrays or pivot table but I can't think of any non-manual way to do this.  Thanks a lot (pardon my poor formatting...).

(Note: the actual problem involves a wide range of dates and >100 names).

**Input**

```
Date    Name    Quan

10/22/2019  Amy 4

10/10/2019  Amy 3

10/23/2019  Amy 1

10/23/2019  Amy 3

10/10/2019  Amy 5

1/31/2011   Cathy   5

1/31/2011   Cathy   2

10/23/2019  Cathy   1

1/31/2011   Cathy   4

1/31/2011   Cathy   5
```

**Output**

```
Date    Name    Quan

10/23/2019  Amy 4

10/22/2019  Amy 4

10/10/2019  Amy 8

10/23/2019  Cathy   1

1/31/2011   Cathy   16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have O365 with dynamic arrays, you can use all formulas

To get the unique list of Date/Name, sorted in the order you show:

```
eg: F1: =SORT(UNIQUE(INDEX(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),{1,2})),{2,1},{1,-1})
```

*Results will spill to the appropriate rows*

To get the sums:

```
eg: H2: =SUMIFS(Table1[Quan],Table1[Date],F2,Table1[Name],G2)
```

[image]

*Note that I used a **Table** and structured references, but you can use regular range references if you prefer.  Structured references have the ability of automatically expanding/contracting if you add/remove data from your table.*

**Note:**

If you don't have the latest functions, you can still use formulas:

To create a unique list, you'll need a helper column in, eg: K

```
K2: =IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Date]&Table1[Name],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$1:K1,Table1[Date]&Table1[Name]),0)),"")
```

Fill down until Blanks

Then, for the Date Column:

```
L2:  =--LEFT(K2,5)
```

Name column:

```
M2:  =MID(K2,6,99)
```

And use SUMIFS as before to get the SUM.

You'll need to sort using the Data/Sort tab.

Another method is by using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` (available in Excel 2010+) to

- Group By Date and Name
- Aggregate with Sum

#### MCode

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Name", type text}, {"Quan", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Name"}, {{"Quant", each List.Sum([Quan]), type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Date", Order.Descending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: @JTg If you have Excel 2010+, you have `Power Query`, aka `Get&Transform`.  In that case, it is simple to group by Date/Name and Sum the Quantity.

Comment: @JTg I have added a method using older style formulas to create your Unique list.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have three rows: Date, Name, and Quan?

If that's the case, you can try using the CONCATENATE formula to combine Date and Name, then use the new "Date & Name" row and the "Quan" row to make pivot table.

[CONCATENATE result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2WAz.jpg)

Pivot table will look for the same "Date & Name" and give you the "Quan" sum you want.

Comment: thanks, i used & to combine the string in a new column, then Remove Duplicate in that column, then use sumifs & countifs to get the statistics i want (in order to avoid using pivot table).

Answer (score 1):

If you use office 2016 or higher (or you have installed PowerQuery-Addin) and you have a lot of Datarow. Group the Data with PowerQuery and without any formula [image]